# Reducing values in a column by an incremental value based on last value in the column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have the following data assigned to c6.

```
In [16]: c6.loc[72822:72870]

72822      NaN
72823    0.000
72824    0.003
...
72867    0.502
72868    0.350
72869    0.227
72870    0.568
Name: new_cases_per_million, dtype: float64
```

I want to replace all of the values from index 72869 (0.227) to index 72822 (NaN) by a decreasing value of 0.01 from the final value 0.568.

So it looks something like this.

```
72822    0.088
...
72868    0.548
72869    0.558
72870    0.568
Name: new_cases_per_million, dtype: float64
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use following code snippet:

```
n = len(c6)
c6['new_col'] = c6.loc[c6.index[-1], 'new_cases_per_million'] - np.arange(n-1, -1, -1) * 0.01
```

Update:
If you only need to update from 72822:72870

```
n = 72870 - 72822
c6.loc[72822:72870, 'new_cases_per_million'] = c6.loc[c6.index[-1], 'new_cases_per_million'] - np.arange(n-1, -1, -1) * 0.01
```